# center div with max width

Tags: html, center

I have 2 divs with max width applied acting them as I want to. One has max width of 900px, while other 820px, and they shrink down if the window size gets smaller as they should.

```
<div id="componentWrapper">
    <div class="thumbContainer"></div>
</div>

#componentWrapper{
  position:absolute;
  height:190px;
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
  top:50%;
  background:red;
  margin-top:-85px;
}

#componentWrapper .thumbContainer{
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  height:180px;
  max-width:420px;
  margin-left:40px;
  margin-right:40px;
  background:green;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DzgQ3/1/

I am trying to center this inside window now with pure CSS if possible. It needs to stay centered even if window gets sized down less than current width of the outer element.

Comment: Seems to work as you describe for me or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

margin:auto; usually works for such things.

Comment: The layout works but my question was how to center the outer div inside the window. And putting the margin will only work if the window size is larger than the outer div, once window size gets smaller than the outer div original size, margin will not make it center any more.

Comment: I think I see what you are trying now, I do not think that there is a way when using position:absolute.

Is this what you need? 
#componentWrapper{
  float:top;
  margin:auto;
  height:190px;
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
  background:red;
  margin-top:30%;
}